# Распаковка deb-пакета С#

Tags: c#, ar, deb

Нужно распаковать deb-пакет на С#. Deb-файл является архивов [ar](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar_(Unix)).

Есть ли какие-то библиотеки для распаковки архива [ar](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar_(Unix)) под С#?

Зачем мне это нужно. Из deb-пакета я хочу получить версию пакета. То есть я хочу добраться до файла control, где я смогу версию пакета прочитать. Может быть есть библиотеки для чтения deb-пакета?

Answer (score 1):

Под Windows deb файлы может открыть архиватор 7zip.

Данная задача весьма специфическая Поэтому, сомневаюсь, что существует готовая "обёртка" под C# предназначенная специально для её решения. Вероятнее всего придётся писать её самому используя 7zip API.

В принципе, есть ещё [SevenZipSharp](http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/). Это "обёртка" для 7zip API под .NET. Хотя эта библиотека официально предназначена в основном для архивов в формате 7z и zip она также может распаковать и deb.

Comment: Нашел библиотеку на С [libarchive](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive). Она позволяет распаковывать ar архив. Попробую собрать ее   прикрутить к С#

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov, возможно, чем-то поможет и python-овская реализация: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/deb-pkg-tools

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, спасибо, вы мой чипидейл.

Answer (score 1):

С помощью библиотеки [libarchive](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive) написал функцию на С++

```
#include "archive.h"
#include "archive_entry.h"

#include <iostream>

/**
    Примеры работы с библиотекой libarchive
    https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/wiki/Examples
*/

/**
 * @brief Копирование данных из одного архива в другой
 * @param ar
 * @param aw
 * @return
 */
static int CopyData(struct archive *ar, struct archive *aw)
{
  int r;
  const void *buff;
  size_t size;
  off_t offset;
  for (;;)
  {
    r = archive_read_data_block(ar, &buff, &size, &offset);
    if (r == ARCHIVE_EOF)
    {
      return (ARCHIVE_OK);
    }
    if (r < ARCHIVE_OK)
    {
      return (r);
    }
    r = archive_write_data_block(aw, buff, size, offset);
    if (r < ARCHIVE_OK)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", archive_error_string(aw));
      return (r);
    }
  }
}

/**
 * @brief ExtractArchive Извечение архива на диск
 * @param filename - входной архив
 * @param outputDir - выходные данные
 * @return
 */
bool ExtractArchive(const char *filename, const char* dest)
{
  struct archive *a;
  struct archive *ext;
  struct archive_entry *entry;
  int flags;
  int r;

  /* Select which attributes we want to restore. */
  flags = ARCHIVE_EXTRACT_TIME;
  flags |= ARCHIVE_EXTRACT_PERM;
  flags |= ARCHIVE_EXTRACT_ACL;
  flags |= ARCHIVE_EXTRACT_FFLAGS;

  a = archive_read_new();
  archive_read_support_format_all(a);
  archive_read_support_compression_all(a);
  ext = archive_write_disk_new();
  archive_write_disk_set_options(ext, flags);
  archive_write_disk_set_standard_lookup(ext);
  if ((r = archive_read_open_filename(a, filename, 10240)))
  {
      fprintf(stderr, "file not found");
      return false;
  }
  for (;;)
  {
    r = archive_read_next_header(a, &entry);
    if (r == ARCHIVE_EOF)
    {
      break;
    }
    if (r < ARCHIVE_OK)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", archive_error_string(a));
    }
    if (r < ARCHIVE_WARN)
    {
        return false;
    }
    const char* currentFile = archive_entry_pathname(entry);
    const std::string fullOutputPath = std::string(dest) + currentFile;
    archive_entry_set_pathname(entry, fullOutputPath.c_str());
    r = archive_write_header(ext, entry);
    if (r < ARCHIVE_OK)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", archive_error_string(ext));
    }
    else if (archive_entry_size(entry) > 0)
    {
          r = CopyData(a, ext);
          if (r < ARCHIVE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", archive_error_string(ext));
          if (r < ARCHIVE_WARN)
          {
            return false;
          }
    }
    r = archive_write_finish_entry(ext);
    if (r < ARCHIVE_OK)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", archive_error_string(ext));
    }
    if (r < ARCHIVE_WARN)
    {
      return -1;
    }
  }
  archive_read_close(a);
  archive_read_free(a);
  archive_write_close(ext);
  archive_write_free(ext);
  return true;
}

int main()
{
    ExtractArchive(pathToDeb, destFolder);
    return 0;
}
```

Функции `ExtractArchive` передаю deb-файл, который он удачно распаковывает в папку `destFolder`. На выходе получаю 3 файла

```
control.tar.gz
data.tar.gz.
dedian-binary.
```

Теперь имея архив `control.tar.gz`, я его распакую(библиотек для работы с архивом tar.gz много, в том числе и для С#) и вытащу из него нужный мне файл `control`.

Теперь сделаю сборку нативной библиотеки и буду дергать функцию ExtractArchive из С#. Это мое быстрое решение проблемы распаковки `ar-архива` под С#.

Comment: Круто. Можете запилить готовую библиотечку с managed-оберткой на гитхаб и нугет.

Comment: у себя в проекте написал С# класс по парсингу метаинформации deb-пакета... надо будет запилить отдельной библиотекой, думал уже.

Comment: И да, можете еще запостить C# код и пометить свой ответ как верный.

Comment: хорошо, выложу пример использования на С#.